# Display Full Text in Excel without truncation

Tags: jasper-reports

How to display Full Text in Excel without truncation programatically?
Currently the data is getting truncated. Is it possible to automatically adjust the row height so as to display the enitre text?

Answer (score 12):

I got these problems also and solved them this way:
For the first one, add the following property to your report:

```
net.sf.jasperreports.print.keep.full.text
```

and put it to `true`

You can also add this property to a specific text field. For more information, refer to [this link](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/config.reference.html#net.sf.jasperreports.print.keep.full.text)

For the second one, as Deathtiny says, add `isStretchWithOverflow=true` to the field that you want, for it to grow with the amount of text in it.

I hope this helps.

Comment: If someone is trying to set by java code, "DefaultJasperReportsContext context = DefaultJasperReportsContext.getInstance(); JRPropertiesUtil.getInstance(context).setProperty("net.sf.jasperreports.print.keep.full.text", "true");" worked for me

Comment: The link is dead.

Comment: True, the link that I had is not working anymore. I tried to look for it but I couldn't find it. However, I have updated the link to point at the doc, so it is still a help.

Comment: Very tidy.  For those like me who had to work out were to put it.  In the **`<jasperReport ...`** as **`<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.print.keep.full.text"  value="true" >`**

Answer (score 6):

Try to set the isStretchWithOverflow property to True for the concerned textfield :

```
<textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
   ...
</textField>
```

It worked for me.

Comment: While using <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true"> its making the particular cell merging with cell in next row and rest of the columns remaining smaller in size, which creating an extra row for other cells.